# How to add numbers in a <td> to an array only if another <td> contains certain text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to push some numbers that are outputted onto my table from my database to an array so I can get the sum of those numbers and then compare them to a different set of data. However, I only want to add numbers where the previous `<td>` contains text 'implementation'. So for example, in this HTML output I'm interested in the `<td>` with class sumCosts, but I only want to add the numbers where the first `<td>`, with the class costPhase, has text of 'implementation'. If you look at the last `<tr>`, the `<td>` with class costPhase contains text 'annual'. I want to omit that specific table data, where the number is 313, from my array.

```
<table class="table text-light">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        <th class="text-start" scope="col">Implementation or Annual</th>
                                        <th class="text-start" scope="col">Category</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Cost ($)</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Hours</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        ***<td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>***
                                        <td class="text-start">emo</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts commas">4,091</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">85</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/1">
                                                <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/1">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        ***<td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>***
                                        <td class="text-start">analysts</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts commas">6,282</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">130.5</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/2">
                                                <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/2">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        ***<td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>***
                                        <td class="text-start">maintenance</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts commas">2,873</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">72.5</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/3">
                                                <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/3">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        ***<td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>***
                                        <td class="text-start">materials</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts commas">1,185</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/4">
                                                <button id="4" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/4">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        ***<td class="text-start costPhase">annual</td>***
                                        <td class="text-start">emo</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts commas">313</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/5">
                                                <button id="5" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/5">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

This is my current function set up. Right now it grabs all the values with class sumCosts

```
let costsArray = [];

$(".sumCosts").each(function () {
            let values = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
            costsArray.push(values);
        });

console.log(costsArray)
```

This is what is logged to the console. (trying to omit 313)

```
(5) [4091, 6282, 2873, 1185, 313]
0: 4091
1: 6282
2: 2873
3: 1185
4: 313
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've tried using an if block with the selector :contains and costPhase.text() === 'implementation'
but neither of these seem to work. The .text() method logs an empty array and the :contains selector logs the same output as above from the original function.

```
if ($('.costPhase').text() === 'implementation') {
$(".sumCosts").each(function () {
            let values = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
            costsArray.push(values);
        });

}

if ($('.costPhase:contains("implementation")')) {
$(".sumCosts").each(function () {
            let values = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
            costsArray.push(values);
        });

}
```

If anyone has any advice on how to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the array you can use `map()` to iterate through all the `.costPhase` elements which contain the word `implementation`. From there you can retrieve the sibling `.sumCosts` and add its value to the array.

To get the total of the values in the resulting array you can use `reduce()`.

Try this:

```js
let values = $('.costPhase:contains("implementation")').map((i, el) => parseInt($(el).siblings('.sumCosts').text().trim().replace(/,/g, ''), 10)).get();
let total = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(values);
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table text-light">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <th class="text-start" scope="col">Implementation or Annual</th>
      <th class="text-start" scope="col">Category</th>
      <th scope="col">Cost ($)</th>
      <th scope="col">Hours</th>
      <th scope="col">Edit</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>
      <td class="text-start">emo</td>
      <td class="text-end sumCosts commas">4,091</td>
      <td class="text-end">85</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/find/costs_hours/1">
          <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/1">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>
      <td class="text-start">analysts</td>
      <td class="text-end sumCosts commas">6,282</td>
      <td class="text-end">130.5</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/find/costs_hours/2">
          <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>
      <td class="text-start">maintenance</td>
      <td class="text-end sumCosts commas">2,873</td>
      <td class="text-end">72.5</td>
      <td>
        <a href="/find/costs_hours/3">
          <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/3">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <td class="text-start costPhase">implementation</td>
      <td class="text-start">materials</td>
      <td class="text-end sumCosts commas">1,185</td>
      <td class="text-end"></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/find/costs_hours/4">
          <button id="4" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-end">
      <td class="text-start costPhase">annual</td>
      <td class="text-start">emo</td>
      <td class="text-end sumCosts commas">313</td>
      <td class="text-end"></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/find/costs_hours/5">
          <button id="5" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/5">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the purpose of the 10 after the .replace()?

Comment: It's the radix of the number being parsed - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters